# Actionscript 2 Scaling Down (not up)

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, scale

I am looking for a way to scale a flash website (using actionscript 2.0) to different resolutions.  People with smaller screen resolutions are having issues seeing my full flash website, and setting the parameters to 100% width and 100% height solve that issue but create another one... It makes the site look out of proportion and pixelated for people with larger screen resolutions.

My question is- how can I use actionscript to scale the website down, but only up to the original stage width and height?  I've seen similar questions asked before, but only using AS3.  Somehow there is a way to switch from exactfit to showall depending on browser size?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the screen resolution then decide the stage scaleMode

> trace(System.capabilities.screenResolutionX);
>
> trace(System.capabilities.screenResolutionY);

```
resX = System.capabilities.screenResolutionX;
resY = System.capabilities.screenResolutionY;
//let's say
if (resX >= 1280 && resY >= 800)
{
    Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
}
else
{
    Stage.scaleMode = "showAll";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested to see if setting the _root's xscale and yscale to different percents would properly adjust the whole thing, get back to use please!

`_root._xscale = 50; //50%`

`_root._yscale = 60; //60%`